# Move "forwards" when KiematicBody is rotated with GDScript

Tags: vector, gdscript

I have a very basic third person controller:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    vel.x = 0
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_forward"):
        vel.x += SPEED * delta
    if Input.is_action_pressed("turn_left"):
        rotate_y(deg2rad(ROTATION_INTENSITY))
    
    move_and_collide(vel)
```

However on rotating and then moving forward, the player will move forward on the x axis instead of the direction the player is pointed. How do i fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Godot 3d get Forward Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48438273/godot-3d-get-forward-vector)

Comment: @Theraot All of the solutions proposed there i either don't understand how to implement or don't work. Could you give an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`KinematicBody`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematicbody.html) is an [`Spatial`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_spatial.html), and as such it is positioned by a [`Transform`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_transform.html).

You can get the `Transform` from the parent `Spatial` (or the root of the scene tree if there is no parent `Spatial`) from the [`transform`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_spatial.html#class-spatial-property-transform) property.

And you can get the `Transform` from root of the scene directly from the [`global_transform`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_spatial.html#class-spatial-property-global-transform) property.

The `Transform` has two parts:

- A [`Vector3`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector3.html) called [`origin`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_transform.html#class-transform-property-origin).
- A [`Basis`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_basis.html) called [`basis`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_transform.html#class-transform-property-basis).

Together they encode a coordinate system. In particular `basis` has three vectors that hold the direction and scale of each of the axis of the coordinate system. *And `origin` has the position of the origin of the coordinate system.*

Now, Godot's coordinate system in 3D is right handed with UP = Y and FORWARD = -Z. *You can confirm this with the constants `Vector3.UP` and `Vector3.FORWARD`. Also notice this differs from Unity and Unreal which are left handed.*

---

Ergo, if you want the direction of one of the axis, you can get it form the basis of the global transform. Like this:

```
var forward := -global_transform.basis.z
var backward := global_transform.basis.z
var left := -global_transform.basis.x
var right := global_transform.basis.x 
var down := -global_transform.basis.y
var up := global_transform.basis.y
```

You could use those to build your velocity in global coordinates, for example:

```
velocity += global_transform.basis.x * SPEED
```

---

Alternatively, you can convert vectors from local to global space with [`to_global`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_spatial.html#class-spatial-method-to-global) (and from global to local with [`to_local`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_spatial.html#class-spatial-method-to-local)) so you can do this:

```
var forward := to_global(Vector3.FORWARD)
var backward:= to_global(Vector3.BACKWARD)
var left := to_global(Vector3.LEFT)
var right := to_global(Vector3.RIGHT)
var down := to_global(Vector3.DOWN)
var up := to_global(Vector3.UP)
```

This also means you may build your velocity in local coordinates, and convert it to global coordinates at the end:

```
move_and_slide(to_global(velocity))
```

And just to be clear, [`move_and_slide`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematicbody.html#class-kinematicbody-method-move-and-slide) expects global coordinates.

---

*I will also point out that it is possible to rotate a vector with [`rotated`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector3.html#class-vector3-method-rotated) and project a vector onto another with [`project`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector3.html#class-vector3-method-project).*